# Assigned and calculate the average data with bash script?

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, grep

I am not familiar with bash script and data manipulation
I have thousands of .txt files which contains 70-80 dose rate value for one Martian day(sol) each .txt is one day.
Here is the example: https://pds-ppi.igpp.ucla.edu/ditdos/viewFile?id=pds://PPI/MSL-M-RAD-3-RDR-V1.0/DATA/SOL_00708_00804/RAD_RDR_2014_215_01_07_0708_V00.TXT

with helped, here is the code so far:

```
for f in /mnt/c/Users/taibo/Desktop/MSL_Script/Data/*.TXT; do
  grep 'START_SOL' $f | awk -F"=" '{if (NR%1==0) {print $2}}' >> startSOL.txt
  grep -A 2 -i 'dose_b' $f | awk '{if ((NR+1)%4==0) {print $0}}' >> rawB_2020-001.txt
  dos2unix startSOL.txt rawB_2020-001.txt
  paste startSOL.txt rawB_2020-001.txt > 2020-001_B_from_RDR.txt
  sed 's/\"//g' 2020-001_B_from_RDR.txt > Btmp.txt
  paste Btmp.txt | awk '{printf("%s %s %.3f %.3f %1i\n",$1,$2,$3,$7,$4)}'
done
```

this is the result from one data file when the script is ran.

---

```
|Sols |    Dose|
|-----|--------|
|1694 | 11.3332|
|     | 11.513 |
|     | 10.6764|
|     |11.18064|
|     | ...    |
```

---

the current code if parsing multiple files the sols and dose will just mixed up. when parsing out I'd like the script to calculate the average of the data per each .txt than assigned this to sol.
something like this

```
|Sols  |Dose rate(average)|
|------|------------------|
|1     | 9.01             |
|2     | 8.05             |
```

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. No links, no images, just plain old text so we have something we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `gawk` is available, would you please try the following:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {
        IGNORECASE = 1          # make the regex case-insensitive
        RS = "\r\n"             # assign input record seoarator to CR+LF
        ORS = "\n"              # assign output record separator to LF
        OFS = "\t"              # assign output field separator to TAB
        print "Sols", "Dose rate(average)"      # print the header line
    }
    /START_SOL/ {               # if the line contains "START_SOL"
        gsub(/.*START_SOL=/, "")
        sol = $0                # then assign "sol" to the value
    }
    c && !--c {                 # extract the 2nd line after "DOSE_B"
        n++                     # increment the number
        sum += $0               # accumulate the dose rate
    }
    /DOSE_B/ {c = 2}            # prepare for the 2nd next line
    ENDFILE {                   # end of each file (available only with gawk)
        print sol, sum / n      # print sol and the average of dose rate
        n = 0; sum = 0          # reset number and the sum
    }
' /mnt/c/Users/taibo/Desktop/MSL_Script/Data/*.TXT | sort -nk1,1
```

- It extracts `sol` value and `dose_b` rates out of each file.
- Whenever the dose_b rate (second line after the keyword) is found,
  the value is added to `sum` and the counter `n` is incremented by 1.
- At the end of each file, sol and the average of dose rate are printed.
- Finally the whole lines are numerically sorted by the `sol` value.

If you feel the execution time is slow, please try the `Perl` alternative:

```
perl -015 -ne '
    BEGIN {print "Sols\tDose rate(average)\n"}
    if (/START_SOL=(\d+)/i) {$sol = $1}
    elsif (/DOSE_B/i) {readline; $sum += readline; $n++}
    elsif (eof) {printf("%s\t%f\n", $sol, $sum / $n); $sum = 0; $n = 0}
' /mnt/c/Users/taibo/Desktop/MSL_Script/Data/*.TXT | sort -nk1,1
```

Comment: I ran the script and got this message: sort: stray character in field spec: invalid field specification ‘1,1\r’ what does this means?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. You may have used a text editor which uses CR+LF as end-of-line characters when you copy&pasted the script. Please use `dos2unix` on the file to convert the end-of-line character to LF.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now though both methods took quite a long time to run

Comment: Okay, let us keep on discussing how we can reduce the execution time if you wish. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: I attempted to run it with the rest of the data. after a while I got this error: (FILENAME=/mnt/c/Users/taibo/Desktop/MSL_Script/Data/RAD_RDR_2015_249_17_18_1097_V00.TXT FNR=91546)  fatal: division by zero attempted. After checking turned out that .txt does not contain any Dose value. so it cannot perform the calculation. anyway of going around this?

Comment: It may depends on how you will treat the file. If you can ignore the file which does not contain any dose values, just add a condition something like `if (n != 0) {...}` to skip the file.